# Call void on possible null object, in one line

Tags: java, null

I use Java8 in my project but i cannot solve this issue with a nice implementation.

```
UIInput textInput = ...;

if (textInput != null)
{
    textInput.setValid(false);
}
```

Is there a solution to check if the object is `null`, and if not, then call the function on it, in **one line** ?!

Comment: Why is this important to you?

Comment: The `if` is nice and clear. What's the issue? Why try to ram it all onto line line? I mean, you *can* (`if (textInput != null)  textInput.setValid(false);`), but why?

Comment: @DaveNewton the importance is about that i do not want to create a method to make a oneliner from it, but i need to use it 5 different points of the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We have a checkstyle built-in and this one-line-if will end up a code like in my snippet :(

Comment: @LeventeTakács - Good, that's the way it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Optional.ofNullable(textInput).ifPresent(x -> x.setValid(false));
```

But this is *not* what `Optional` was designed for...

Comment: I'm downvoting because I have people at work doing this. Please, for the love of Knuth, don't ever abuse optionals like this. Two method calls and an object creation just to avoid a literal null-check, because someone somewhere got the idea that null checks are bad... Hey folks, ofNullable(...) literally does a null check!

Comment: @Torben thx for the comment on the down-vote, this rarely happens around here! for this simple case, I would agree, but there are cases where I (ab)use this pattern quite a lot _at my workplace_; this sometimes is a lot more readable, to me, at least

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. There's a third method call when ifPresent invokes the lambda.

Comment: @Torben if you are on that path - you can add _besides the Objects being created for this_ and thus GC-ed also

Answer (score 3):

**Don't.**

What you have is easily readable for anyone with some Java knowledge. Any one-liner misusing a construct intended for something else will take most people way more time to read and understand than this will. And likely some people will misread it and have to read it again later when it does not behave like they expect during a debugging session.

Brevity / Number of lines of code is not an ultimate measure for readability or quality.

What you can do, if this is at the wrong level of detail compared with the rest of your method, is abstract it away with a single speaking method call. Say, create a method 'ensureTextInputIsSet' that just contains this code and returns the potentially modified object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, at the end i rather use the _if_ statement, instead of "abusing" the Optionals (as @Torben described)

Answer (score 1):

If a variable may be null, an object is optional, then:

```
Optional<UIInput> textInput = ...;
```

With a circumstantial, but always safe usage:

```
textInput.ifPresent(ti -> ti.setValid(false));
```

And nice chaining, for instance for `Optional<UIInput>` to `Optional<String>` calling a method on the `UIInput`.

```
String s = textInput.map(UIInput::getText).orElse("");
```